# I want to remove newline character if the line not start with a space by unix command

Tags: bash

Input:

```
 NOR2X2 U68695 
(n102890)
 AO21X4 U68696 ( .
A0(mbw4[84])
311)
```

Output:

```
 NOR2X2 U68695 (n102890)
 AO21X4 U68696 ( .A0(mbw4[84])311)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk to do that:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]/{if (s) print s; s=$0; next}
{s=s $0}
END{ print s }' file
```

Or a perl:

```
perl -0777 -lpE 's/(^\h[\s\S]*?)(?=^\h|\Z)/$1=~s|\n||gr."\n"/gme' file
```

Either prints:

```
 NOR2X2 U68695 (n102890)
 AO21X4 U68696 ( .A0(mbw4[84])311)
```